# the difference between using esc_html and esc_attr in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, escaping

I look at this example:

esc_html would be used inside of html for example between a `<p>` tag

```
<p><?php echo esc_html( $some_variable ); ?></p>
```

esc_attr would be used for escaping attribute values on html tags like so:

```
<p my-attribute="<?php echo esc_attr( $some_variable ); ?>"></p>
```

And I can't apply it to my code, am I doing it right?

Can anyone elaborate/explain with my live example what shielding is needed and why.

I'd be happy to get any answers on this case:

```
1. echo '<div class="bg-primary ' . esc_attr( $theme-name_header_class ) . '" id="subheader">';
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $theme-name_l['url'] ); ?>" class="<?php if ( $theme-name_l['active'] ) { echo 'current-lng'; } ?> inline-flex">
    <?php echo esc_html( $theme-name_l['language_code'] ); ?>
</a>
2. <a href="/<?php echo esc_attr( $theme-name_lng ); ?>/" class="<?php if ( $theme-name_current_uri === $theme-name_lng ) { echo 'current-lng'; } ?> inline-flex items-center text-xs lg:text-base h-5 pl-2 pr-3 leading-none text-accent border-accent capitalize" aria-label="<?php echo esc_attr( $theme-name_lng ); ?>" >
        <?php echo esc_html( $theme-name_lng ); ?>
</a>
3. <div class="item-content-mega__desc">
        <?php echo esc_html( $theme-name_children_post_desc ); ?>
</div>
4. <a class="px-4" href="<?php echo esc_url( $theme-name_parent_post_url ); ?>" aria-label="<?php echo esc_attr( $theme-name_parent_post_title ); ?>" class="transition-colors <?php if ( $theme-name_parent_post_url === $theme-name_current_url ) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
            <span class="capitalize"><?php echo esc_attr( ucfirst( strtolower( $theme-name_parent_post_title ) ) ); ?></span>
</a>
```

Comment: It's all about protecting you from XSS injection attacks. AFAIK you should be using esc_url in the href attributes, so example 2 would be wrong. Example 4 inside the span is wrong too because clearly that's not an attribute, it's body text so you'd use esc_html. More info and examples: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/,  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298963/what-is-the-use-of-esc-attr-function.

Comment: P.S. Your examples 1 and 3 appears to be ok.

Comment: Thanks. And what do you think about this: `echo '<' . esc_html( $theme-name_title_size ) . '  class="text-primary">'` and `<input value="" placeholder="<?php echo esc_html__( 'Price of Columbia mold*', 'theme-name' ); ?>"`?

Comment: Well, based on what I've just told you, what do **you** think, and why?

Comment: I think the first example should be left that way, because no attibutes are used.
The second example uses the attribute "placeholder" and you have to put "esc_attr" there, even though we're escaping text.

Comment: You're correct certainly about the second one because you're escaping an attribute value (all of it is "text" at the end of the day, so that's not a consideration, it's the context which is important). The first one...hmm, it's _inside_ a HTML tag, so it's not body content or an attribute value. I guess it would be expecting to create the tag type name (e.g. `div` or something), but of course the danger is that it actually contains something else entirely. So I think you're correct that esc_html is the appropriate solution there.

Comment: Thank you so much for telling me all this in detail. I hope I understand it better:)